# como poner el focus en el ultimo ítem de un listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, customadapter

como poner el focus en el ultimo ítem de un listview?

estoy llenando un listview atravez de una adapter ..

```
CustomCursorAdapterListaPedidoMaterial  customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapterListaPedidoMaterial(ActAlmacenmovAlmaCambUbi.this,cRecepcionPedido,"list_almacen_cambio_ubicacion");
                list_Listas.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

todo muy bien..

y me muestra el item inicial en pantalla .

pero lo que busco, es mostrar el ultimo item .. hacer el scroll hasta el ultimo item justo despues de llenar/mostrar el listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes forzar en hacer scroll a la última posición, con crear un selección al último, extraído de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606530/listview-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-list-after-updating-the-list)

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    myListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona:

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante adapter = new Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante(this,datos);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setSelection(datos.size() - 1);  //Esta es la linea clave. Indicamos que el focus al listView se realize en el último elemento de este.
```